UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: empty/missing DT_HASH/DT_GNU_HASH in /lib/arm64/libAgoraRtcWrapper.so" (new hash type from the future?)
I added a video calling portion of my app using agora rtc, but whenever the user tries to launch the feature, the android device disconnects and shows this error:
UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: empty/missing DT_HASH/DT_GNU_HASH in "/data/app/~~21DAh8LmnQnRAVuHNCBmHQ==/com.wali.app-MJ0U37SYt1qL1vVJyvsz5g==/lib/arm64/libAgoraRtcWrapper.so" (new hash type from the future?)

I tried using an emulator with 16 kb size, but it still didnt work.
Here is my flutter doctor:
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.24.0-1.0.pre.554, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)• Flutter version 3.24.0-1.0.pre.554 on channel master at /Users/walihasan/developer/flutter• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git• Framework revision 5a04b4dda9 (19 hours ago), 2024-08-12 12:57:22 -0700• Engine revision bcf2dcc09a• Dart version 3.6.0 (build 3.6.0-140.0.dev)• DevTools version 2.38.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)• Android SDK at /Users/walihasan/Library/Android/sdk• Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer• Build 15F31d• CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents• Flutter plugin can be installed from: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter• Dart plugin can be installed from: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.0)• VS Code at /Users/walihasan/Downloads/Visual Studio Code 2.app/Contents• Flutter extension version 3.94.0

[✓] Connected device (5 available)• sdk gphone16k arm64 (mobile)    • emulator-5554             • android-arm64  • Android 15 (API 35) (emulator)• Wali (mobile)                   • 00008120-000869A00AF8A01E • ios            • iOS 17.5.1 21F90• macOS (desktop)                 • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64• Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad     • darwin         • macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64• Chrome (web)                    • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.100

[✓] Network resources• All expected network resources are available.

Here is my app/build.gradle:
plugins {id "com.android.application"// START: FlutterFire Configurationid 'com.google.gms.google-services'// END: FlutterFire Configurationid "kotlin-android"// The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"}

android {namespace = "com.example.wali"compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersionndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId = "com.wali.app"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
    minSdk = 23
    targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode = flutter.versionCode
    versionName = flutter.versionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

}

flutter {source = "../.."}

Can someone please help me?
I tried updating android mk, but I literally don't have that folder in a jni directory as other stack overflow questions have said I should. I use vs code and maybe that could be a reason of the problem. My gradle version is also 8.0.
